# umlaut vs. diaeresis (double-dot)

Tags: accents

What is the difference between `\H{o}` and `\"{o}`? Is the first an umlaut (for German) and the second a diaeresis (for English)? E.g., for setting "Moeller" and "cooperation".

Comment: The `\H` accent is used in Hungarian and `\H{o}` roughly denotes the same sound as `\"{o}`, but the vowel is long in the former case, short in the latter. German only uses `\"{o}`. Don't use `\H` except for Hungarian.

Comment: Here is an example of its use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s. I caught a copyeditor (who looked at spellings etc) who changed my `\H{o}` to ö, to which I of course complained ;-)

Comment: I've read that the umlaut and double-dot have different histories, and the umlaut used to be two vertical strokes, but I'll just use \"{o} instead of (Hungarian) \H{o}. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ToddHarrop Umlaut used to be an `e` after the vowel that moved above the vowel and degraded to two dots.

Comment: @daleif Don't you hate it when editors do that??!!  Also, thanks for the `Erd\H{o}s` link.  While I am not a mathematician, I knew of him, but not all the fascinating details.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I just think the person did not know any better. I've also gotten a manuscript back where the copyeditor wanted `.` to be added after each floating table. Luckily we had the last word. Clearly it was not a person who previously had dealt with science publications.

Comment: @daleif That an editor doesn't know something is fine.  That an editor assumes to the contrary is where the problem begins.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- an editor should know when something needs to be looked up.  *any* assuming is generally wrong.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You know what they say: when you "assume", you make an "ass" out of "u" and "me" `:^)`

Comment: @barbarabeeton, and if your own system is not able to even write `\H{o}` and most of the literature you normally use gets it wrong? It is quite normal to see it spelled as Erdös or another Hunragian mathematician König (should be spelled Kőnig). A lot of western publishers routinely get this wrong.

Comment: @daleif -- fortunately i work for a publisher that doesn't have that problem.  (`Erd\H{o}s` has *always* been a presence.)  the expanding use of unicode should make this less of a problem ... we can hope.

Answer (score 7):

For the “double acute accent”, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_acute_accent

The accent is used in Hungarian to denote the long variant of ö and ü and realized in TeX with `\H{o}` and `\H{u}`. For example, the correct spelling of a great mathematician is

```
Erd\H{o}s
```

that gives

> Erdős

German doesn't use this accent, so

```
M\"{o}ller
```

is the correct input. The same accent can be used in English for words such as “coöperation”, but I don't think it's necessary nor widely used.

Comment: Note that whilst nowadays a diaeresis is marked using the same symbol as an umlaut, they have different histories and typographic traditions. (Perhaps a better example of a diaeresis in English would be the names Zoë or Chloë, as these spelling are commonly used.)

Comment: Interestingly, it's becoming quite common to see the acute substituted for the trema, as in Chloé. Zoé doesn't seem as common. But isn't this all a little off-topic for TeX.SE?